# Regex - trying to get the 5 digit words extracted from the string (presto)

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I am trying to retrieved each sequence of 5 numbers / letters that are in brackets just like this example:

`accuracy of action - [1232d, 74294, qw23t, 23d45, 76wer, 12874] march`

and from that I want to extract `1232d 74294 qw23t 23d45 76wer 12874`

I know that to extract only a single 5 digit sequence in square brackets I can do `\[[a-z0-9 ]{5,7}\]` But I don't know how to do retrieve various 5 digit sequences.

Comment: It looks like you simply want to extract all the consecutive "words" from between the brackets, right? Or can there be any "words" that you do not want to extract? Like, can there be `accuracy of action - [1232d, 76wer111111111, 12874] march`? And then, do you need to extract `76wer111111111`? Just clarifying, since you say you want to get "5 digit words", but `1232d` is not a digit word, it contains a letter.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I actually want all consecutive sequences of 5 letters and digit . so basically I want everything that is inside the square brackets

Comment: Try `SELECT regexp_extract_all(col, '(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\[)(\w+)(?=[^\]\[]*])', 1);`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RomJaS/1/).

Comment: Does it work as intended with your data?

Comment: Hey, yes it did work, but I am trying to figure out a way to have the sequences of digit/letters split in different rows now. So basically I want 1  '1232d' for 1 row without square brackets and comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, since all the words inside `[...]` consist of 5 alphanumeric chars, you can use

```java
(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\[)(\w+)(?=[^\]\[]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RomJaS/1/).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\[)` - either the end of the preceding successful match and a comma and zero or more whitesapces, or a `[` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?=[^\]\[]*])` - followed with zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`.